# Return the next row value that meets a specific criteria

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I have the below data, where the first seven columns are data I've collected through a query. The last column (Desired) is what I want to show based on the first seven columns, but I can't quite there.

The desired column is supposed to return a value based on this criteria:

1. If Current = Dest, then show the ToLoc column.
2. If Current <> Dest, then show the next value in the ToLoc column where Current = Dest (ordered by EntryTime and partitioned by Box and Step).

Code:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
           (
               Box CHAR(20),
               Step CHAR(20),
               Curr CHAR(20),
               Dest CHAR(20),
               FromLoc CHAR(20),
               ToLoc CHAR(20),
               EntryTime datetime,
               Desired CHAR(20)
           )

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES  
('A','40','Lane 1','Lane 3','Storage A','Tunnel B',45212.8375810185,'Storage B'),
('A','40','Lane 2','Lane 3','Tunnel B','Tunnel C',45212.8377777778,'Storage B'),
('A','40','Lane 3','Lane 3','Tunnel C','Storage B',45212.8395833333,'Storage B'),
('A','40','Lane 4','Lane 4','Storage C','Storage C',45212.8460532407,'Storage C'),
('A','40','Lane 5','Lane 5','Storage D','Storage D',45213.1816666667,'Storage D'),
('A','40','Lane 6','Lane 6','Storage E','Storage E',45213.1839930556,'Storage E'),
('A','40','Lane 7','Lane 7','Storage F','Storage F',45214.2659837963,'Storage F'),
('A','40','Lane 8','Lane 8','Storage G','Storage G',45214.2679513889,'Storage G'),
('B','41','Lane 9','Lane 9','Storage H','Storage H',45212.8965162037,'Storage H'),
('B','41','Lane 10','Lane 10','Storage I','Storage I',45212.9026967593,'Storage I'),
('B','41','Lane 11','Lane 11','Storage J','Storage J',45212.9909606481,'Storage J')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I have tried using LAST_VALUE but it's not returning what I expected:

```
SELECT
    LAST_VALUE(To) OVER (PARTITION BY Box, Step, Dest ORDER BY EntryTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following provides a solution for your requirements, I have implemented the required logic for both conditions in a *cross apply*:

```
select * 
from t
cross apply(
  select top(1) ToLoc
  from t t2
  where t2.Box = t.Box and t2.Step = t.Step 
    and (
      (t.Curr = t.Dest and t2.EntryTime = t.EntryTime) or
      (t2.Curr = t2.Dest and t2.EntryTime > t.EntryTime)
    )
  order by t2.EntryTime
)d(CalculatedDesired)
order by Box, Step, EntryTime;
```

See a [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aOaDF88C)

Comment: I think creiteria case #1 can just be thought of as a special case of case #2, so the subselect condition can be simplified to `... and t2.Curr = t2.Dest and t2.EntryTime >= t.EntryTime`. See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-iDn_Omn). There could be ambiguity if duplicate `EntryTime` values exists for the same `Box` and `Step`, but that ambiguity exists for both forms of the query.

Comment: Yes, that's possibly a simplification! Hopefully the OP will revisit their question and comment.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I see what you mean about case #1 being a subset of case #2: I agree. There should never be a duplicate EntryTime for the same Box and Step in my environment, so that wouldn't be a factor. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is not "elegant" but, it seems to work:

```
select tmain.*, 
(select ToLoc from @t where EntryTime = 
CASE
    WHEN tmain.curr = tmain.dest THEN tmain.EntryTime
    ELSE 
        (select min(entrytime) entrytime from @t tsub
        where entrytime > tmain.entrytime 
        and tsub.box = tmain.box and tsub.step = tmain.step --partition by box and step
        and tsub.curr = tsub.dest)
END
) DesiredCalc
from @t tmain
```